# np.where returns wrong index

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I use a nested list `wl_list`.
And I want to find an index of the minimal residue between `0.21` and the second value in the list. To demonstrate what I mean, look at this:

```
In [107]: wl_list 
Out[107]: 
[[0.21, 0.20033118267365396],
 [0.21, 0.20108968331942148],
 [0.21, 0.2018455976996333],
 [0.21, 0.20259889407493714],
 [0.21, 0.20334954134171523],
 [0.21, 0.20409750903553264],
 [0.21, 0.20484276733424645],
 [0.21, 0.20558528706077894],
 [0.21, 0.2063250396855564],
 [0.21, 0.20706199732861758],
 [0.21, 0.20779613276139344],
 [0.21, 0.20852741940816347]]

In [108]: np.diff(wl_list)
Out[108]: 
array([[-0.00966882],
       [-0.00891032],
       [-0.0081544 ],
       [-0.00740111],
       [-0.00665046],
       [-0.00590249],
       [-0.00515723],
       [-0.00441471],
       [-0.00367496],
       [-0.002938  ],
       [-0.00220387],
       [-0.00147258]])

In [109]: np.min(np.abs(np.diff(wl_list)))
Out[109]: 0.0014725805918365253
```

Then I want to use `np.where` to get essentially the last index in this case, but what I get instead is this:

```
In [110]: np.where(np.min(np.abs(np.diff(wl_list))))
Out[110]: (array([0]),)

In [111]: i = np.where(np.min(np.abs(np.diff(wl_list))))[0][0]

In [112]: wl_list[i]
Out[112]: [0.21, 0.20033118267365396]
```

I don't understand this behavior, could you please explain what do I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) here (in the case where the minimum value could be repeated, it would return the first match):

```
ix = np.abs(np.diff(wl_list)).argmin()
# 11
wl_list[ix]
# array([0.21      , 0.20852742])
```

---

`np.where` gives you the indices where a condition is satisfied, i.e. where there are `True`s in an array. Your input though, is just the result of `np.min(...)`. That won't give you the index where the value takes place in the array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's very useful. But I need the index as output, not the value itself. Do you perhaps know how to get it?

Comment: The index is the result of `argmin`. Updated @astrodi

Comment: Great! Thank you again, @yatu!

Comment: Might be worthwhile to mention that `argmin` will only will return the first occurrence where the condition is met.

Comment: Doesn't look like the different between values in those cols will be repeated. But yeh, in that case, the first match will be returned @rikisa